# Looping through files in a folder and deleting files older than n number of days in Pentaho PDI

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I am new to PDI. I have a requirement where I need to delete files which are older than certain number of days. The file name is like ABCD_20180705 where ABC_ is fixed and only the dates are contacted everyday.

Comment: I meant dates are concatenated to ABC_